# Programatically Create and UITabBar and detect changes

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uitabbar

So im trying to make an application with a UITabBar not a UITabBarController so i declared the UITabBar in my headers as to make it acessable from all my methods, so to make it i just did:

```
tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:tabBar];
```

and i used an NSMutableArray to add my objects... but in my headers i also delcaired:

```
@interface RootViewController: UIViewController {
IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBar *tabBar;
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
```

an then i made a simple function to go along with it:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %d", item.tag);
}
```

But then when I go into the app and try to change the tab, the log returns nothing, the selected tab changes, but my log gets nothing! I've seen this function set up to do this job all over the internet, and i dont understand why it wont work for my code.
So could anybody mybe tell me what im doing wrong that this function wont pick up the tab change?

Comment: You forgot to set up you controller as a delegate for this tab bar.

Comment: But the point is that i do not want a UITabBarController

Comment: `UITabBarController` has nothing to do with this. Method `tabBar:didSelectItem:` is called on some object only when this object is a delegate of a tab bar (instance of `UITabBar` class, value of your `tabBar` field). `tabBar.delegate = self;` after `tabBar = ...` line will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RootViewController.h, do this:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

In RootViewController.m, do this:

```
@interface RootViewController () <UITabBarDelegate>
@end

@implementation RootViewController {
    UITabBar *tabBar;
}

#pragma mark UITabBarDelegate methods

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %d", item.tag);
}

#pragma mark UIViewController methods

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];
    tabBar.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tabBar];
}

@end
```

This layout takes advantage of the new LLVM compiler features of modern Objective-C.

You don't need a property since no user of the class needs access to the tab bar. You don't need to mark anything as an `IBOutlet` since you aren't using Interface Builder to setup the tab bar. You don't declare the tab bar delegate method in the .h file since no client of the class will be calling that method.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! Great solution, it was all avout delegates i guess huh?

Comment: Yes, ultimately your issue was never setting the tab bar's delegate to your view controller. Everything else was just cleanup to demonstrate a nice way to code this by taking advantage of modern Objective-C.

Comment: Not at all. I assumed ARC. There were no memory issues (if using ARC).

Comment: Automatic Reference Counting, as opposed to MRC (Manual Reference Counting).

Comment: Ok, ill look into it, im new to C languages, and I learned tha basics of C quickly and went right to Obj-C as a first choise rather than c++ but i've been doing my research :D

Comment: Any idea on how to do this for `- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` with UIWebKitDelegate?

Comment: nvm! <UITabBarDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>